# How do i add HTML classes to built-in 'User' form?

Tags: python, django

I want to add some HTML classes to set of built-in Django model `User` that imports from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`.

---

I searched this information about 1 day, and found nothing. All answers only applicable to self created models, not `User` model.

GOAL:

Add `form-control` HTML class to both `password1`, `password2` and `username` fields.

---

UPD 1:

Now I understand how to add classes to forms. Thanks to `Daniel Roseman` for that. But now i got 1 more problem. Why fields `password1` and `password2` doesn't get provided classes? My form looks like this:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "password1", "password2"]
        widgets = {
            "username": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "password1": forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "password2": forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

When rendering, it applies that `form-control` class only to `username` field. Also I tried to use just `password` field instead of `password1` and `password2`. And then, provided HTML class successfully applied to this field. I think there is something wrong with `password1` and `password2` fields. What do you think?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. What do HTML classes have to do with a model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i need to add `form-control` HTML class to `username`, `password1` and `password2` fields of `User` model.

Comment: No, you need to do that in a form.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok then, my question about that also. how to achive that? my form only has `class Meta` with `fields` list and `model` variable that refers to `User` model.

Comment: [Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

Comment: @DanielRoseman One more thing. Why class works fine for `username` field, but not for both `password` fields? Provided class just dont apper in tag

Answer (score 0):

When I used from my `UPD 1`, I decided to debug what's going on inside this form. Firstly, I looked into source code of `UserCreationForm` and tried to update `widget`s dict with `update` method. It looked like this:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.password1.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.password2.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

    ...
```

But, with next time I opened link where this form is located, I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'password1'

Full traceback can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/99HSya0k) (pastebin).

---

After this error, I looked into source code of `UserCreationForm` one more time. I found that in source code `widget` updating with a little bit different syntax:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:
        self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': True})
```

Though, it is not `password1` or `password2` fields, I decided to update `widget`s similar way. Now my overrided `__init__` method looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["password1"].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
    self.fields["password2"].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

Now all works as I want. Provided class applies to both `password` fields.

---

But I still think that I do something wrong way. I'll be glad if someone offers a better way to achieve this result.